# Cisco VPN client software use licenses?

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I am doing research into Cisco ASA appliances and SSL/Anyconnect. What is the actual cost to do a VPN with a Firewall by Cisco? I never realized they actually charged and do they charge per connection? Or per VPN set up.

Do the licenses last certain amount of time or once you purchase it , its permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cisco ASA comes with some license depending on the bundle you purchase. A basic ASA 5510 bundle comes with 2 SSL/Any-connect VPN license and 250 IPSec VPN.

The license is perpetual. It's on a simultaneous connection basis.

This may help further: 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6032/ps6094/ps6120/overview_c78-527488.html

Comment: Thank you for finding  that link. I wanted to ask: So as a basic license with an ASA i can have just two 2 SSL clients working simultaneously ? I wasn't sure if that was the deal. thankyou.

Comment: Correct: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6032/ps6094/ps6120/product_data_sheet0900aecd802930c5.html